# Phaser.events.onInputOut not dispatched

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm trying to make a sprite moving when the mouse is over it and I'd like it to stop when the mouse is not over it anymore.

Here is my code:

```
mySprite.events.onInputOver.add(() => touchMouse = true);
mySprite.events.onInputOut.add(() => touchMouse = false);
```

and

```
update() {
  if (touchMouse) {
    mySprite.x += 5;
  }
}
```

My sprite is correctly moving but the onInputOut signal is not dispatched if I don't move the pointer out of the **initial** sprite position!! This result in my sprite moving out of my pointer and continuing its journey until I move my mouse...

Is it a phaser bug? Has anyone a solution to make this work?

Thank you very much and have a good day,

Simon

**Edit:**

I just tried to use the Phaser.InputHandler object instead but I got the same kind of bug. Here is the code:

```
update() {
  if (mySprite.input.pointerOver()) {
    mySprite.x += 5;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered my question in the [html5gamedevs](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/30459-phasereventsoninputout-not-dispatched/) forum.

> Phaser doesn't ordinarily update inputOver/inputOut events while the pointer isn't moving. You need to set pointer.dirty = true for that.